# No output from file type detection script

Tags: shell

I'm trying to run a script to set what kind of compression is used and unpacking compression types.

```
for file; do
local t_of=$(file -i "$file")



case "$t_of" in
*hey/x-bzip2*)    echo "bzip2 file found";;
*hey/gzip*)       echo "gzip file found";;
*hey/zip*)        echo "zip file found";;
*hey/x-xz*)       echo "xz file found";;
*hey/x-compress*) echo "compressed file found";;
?)                        echo "${file} cannot be extarcted";;


esac
done
```

There's no output when I run it.

Comment: Use `*)` for the default case.

Comment: @JohnKugelman and now it give me this error:



./unpack: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `file'
./unpack: line 9: `    *hey/x-bzip2*)    echo "bzip2 file found";;'

Comment: What exactly did you change?

Comment: @chepner nothing exept what he told me up comment to change, maybe it's also because it's not showing the unzziped files?

Comment: But what, exactly, did you do? Did you replace `?` with `*` and nothing else? Because that doesn't produce a syntax error.

Comment: @chepner no i added * to ?) , like this *?)

Comment: That's not what John told you to do, and while semantically slightly incorrect (it won't match empty strings), it won't cause the syntax error you are reporting. Something about your actual script doesn't match what you've posted.

Comment: @chepner i'm sorry but i didn't change nothing (the name of my file is unpack)

Comment: The code shown above does not produce a syntax error.

Comment: @chepner ok now it's fixed, but still not showing me nothing, is there any chance the reason for that is that the files are unzipped?

Comment: Why are you matching against `hey/` instead of `application/`?

Comment: @chepner because that is the name of my main folder, where all the files and unzipped files are.

Comment: You seem to be confusing file paths with MIME types. Have you looked at the actual value of `t_of` yet?

Comment: @chepner what do you mean?

Comment: If it's a bzip2 file, the mime type (produced by `file -i`) is `application/x-bzip2`, which is what I suspect you are trying to match against, not something involving the name of the directory that `file` is in (which may or may not even show up in the output of `file -i`, depending on what the value of `$file` actually is).

Comment: @chepner first of all thanks for the note about application, secondly t_of is just as a verb

Comment: anyone can help?